# Ticker text overlapping

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this nice little continuous text ticker, but unfortunately when the text reaches a certain length, it starts overlapping. I cannot for the life of me figure out a solution.

I've set everything to "display:block" but that does not seem to make a difference.

```js
$('#tick2').html($('#tick').html());
//alert($('#tick2').offset.left);

var temp=0,intervalId=0;
$('#tick li').each(function(){
  var offset=$(this).offset();
  var offsetLeft=offset.left;
  $(this).css({'left':offsetLeft+temp});
  temp=$(this).width()+temp+10;
});
$('#tick').css({'width':temp+1000, 'margin-left':'20px'});
temp=0;
$('#tick2 li').each(function(){
  var offset=$(this).offset();
  var offsetLeft=offset.left;
  $(this).css({'left':offsetLeft+temp});
  temp=$(this).width()+temp+10;
});
$('#tick2').css({'width':temp+40,'margin-left':temp+40});

function abc(a,b) {  

    var marginLefta=(parseInt($("#"+a).css('marginLeft')));
    var marginLeftb=(parseInt($("#"+b).css('marginLeft')));
    if((-marginLefta<=$("#"+a).width())&&(-marginLefta<=$("#"+a).width())){
        $("#"+a).css({'margin-left':(marginLefta-1)+'px'});
    } else {
        $("#"+a).css({'margin-left':temp});
    }
    if((-marginLeftb<=$("#"+b).width())){
        $("#"+b).css({'margin-left':(marginLeftb-1)+'px'});
    } else {
        $("#"+b).css({'margin-left':temp});
    }
} 

     function start() { intervalId = window.setInterval(function() { abc('tick','tick2'); }, 10) }

     $(function(){

          start();
     });
```

```css
#tick li, #tick2 li { list-style-type:none; float:left; padding-right:20px; position:absolute; left:0px;}
#tick, #tick2 { position:relative; display:block; width:100%; margin:0; content=""; display:table; height:0px; }
#outer{width:100%;height:230px; overflow:hidden; background:#EEEEEE;}
#outer span {text-decoration:none; color:#333; font-size:46px; padding-right: 200px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="outer">
  <ul id ="tick">
    <li><span>I am FirstI am FirstI am FirstI am FirstI am FirstI am FirstI am FirstI am FirstI am FirstI am First</span></li>
    <li><span>I am Second</span></li>
    <li><span>I am Third</span></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tick2"></div>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with how javascript determines "width".  Generally, when determining the width of an element javascript only ever cares about the visible portion of the element.  That being the case, your width calculations are never exceeding the width of the viewport.  One way around this is to use `scrollWidth` to calculate the true width of an element.  With a little tweaking, your code can be adapted to calculate that and use that for your `left` values.

```js
$('#tick2').html($('#tick').html());
//alert($('#tick2').offset.left);

var temp=0,intervalId=0;
$('#tick li').each(function(){
  var offset=$(this).offset();
  var offsetLeft=offset.left;
  $(this).css({'left':temp});
  temp=this.scrollWidth+temp;
  $(this).addClass('done');
});
$('#tick').css({'width':temp+1000, 'margin-left':'20px'});
temp=0;
$('#tick2 li').each(function(){
  var offset=$(this).offset();
  var offsetLeft=offset.left;
  $(this).css({'left':offsetLeft+temp});
  temp=$(this).width()+temp+10;
});
$('#tick2').css({'width':temp+40,'margin-left':temp+40});

function abc(a,b) {  

    var marginLefta=(parseInt($("#"+a).css('marginLeft')));
    var marginLeftb=(parseInt($("#"+b).css('marginLeft')));
    if((-marginLefta<=$("#"+a).width())&&(-marginLefta<=$("#"+a).width())){
        $("#"+a).css({'margin-left':(marginLefta-1)+'px'});
    } else {
        $("#"+a).css({'margin-left':temp});
    }
    if((-marginLeftb<=$("#"+b).width())){
        $("#"+b).css({'margin-left':(marginLeftb-1)+'px'});
    } else {
        $("#"+b).css({'margin-left':temp});
    }
} 

     function start() { intervalId = window.setInterval(function() { abc('tick','tick2'); }, 10) }

     $(function(){

          start();
     });
```

```css
#tick li, #tick2 li { list-style-type:none; float:left; padding-right:20px; position:absolute; left:0px;}
#tick, #tick2 { position:relative; display:block; width:100%; margin:0; content=""; display:table; height:0px; }
#outer{width:100%;height:230px; overflow:hidden; background:#EEEEEE;}
#outer span {text-decoration:none; color:#333; font-size:46px; padding-right: 200px;}


#tick li:not(.done), #tick2 li:not(.done) {
 overflow: scroll;
 width: 0px;
 white-space: nowrap;
 padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="outer">
  <ul id ="tick">
    <li><span>I am FirstI am FirstI am FirstI am FirstI am FirstI am FirstI am FirstI am FirstI am FirstI am First</span></li>
    <li><span>I am Second</span></li>
    <li><span>I am Third</span></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tick2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: So since I'm now calculating width, does that mean text can no longer continuously scroll?

Comment: @tekgirl I don't quite understand the question.  The overlapping of the text is due to unexpected/incorrect calculation of the element width by the browser.  The scrolling would be handled by the code logic.  What is the exact expected result of your code?  I assume you intended it to scroll like a marquee?  If that's the case, why are you using absolute positioning?

Comment: Oh sorry. In my original code, the ticker restarts creating an infinite loop which I want to keep. I liked that. Removing absolute positioning or changing it to relative doesn't seem to affect it one way or the other.

Comment: @tekgirl have you found the way of creating infinite overlaping ticker ?